# How to get current location of the user on Google maps in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, google-maps, c#-4.0, google-maps-api-3, bing-maps

When the user opens my Windows Phone app, he should be shown his current position - either using Google maps or Bing maps.
I tried to integrate Bing maps in my app, but the question is:

How do I locate the exact or nearby location of the user?

Answer (score 1):

The map is just a control, on which you can show your position if you got it from the **GeoCoordinateWatcher**. You can look for good examples (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dragoman/archive/2010/09/21/wp7-code-using-the-geolocation-api.aspx ) on the web but if you need I can help to implement it too.

Comment: Thank you..

Its very helpful..
:)

Comment: A bit easier one: http://windowsphone7developerguide.blograby.com/windows-phone-using-location-services-gps/ 
The other is a better solution but it uses RX and it can be a little hard to understand for the first sight.

And you need to be carefull updating UI data from Postion/StatusCahnged eventhadlers, because it works on a background thread.